# How do you make a div and its content stretch with the browser?

Tags: css

I am using media queries to target for mobile phones. Right now I am targeting 0 - 699px max-width. I have a **li** with an image inside. What I am trying to do is have the image and **li** expand a little as the viewport stretches.

So if I was expanding the viewport from 0 - 699px. The images and **li** gradually get bigger in both width and height. No huge differences but noticeable.

In my example everything is fixed. It doesn't matter how far I stretch the viewport, the sizes stay the same.

How do I have an **li** or div and its contents stretch a little in height and width as the viewport stretches?

Here is what I have been working on:

http://codepen.io/daydreamer/pen/jxlcn

Everything is fixed. When I adjust the width of the viewport horizontally, I want the **li** and the img to get a little bit bigger.

Here are the css specs I am using:

**.picture** is the image container 
**.list** li is the **li** 
**li img** is the image

```
 .picture {
   width:100px;
   min-height:100px;
   max-height:auto;
   position:absolute;
   left:0;
 }

 .list li {
   background:silver;
   min-height:100px;
   position:relative; 
 }

 li img {
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `li` and `div` in your sample code are 100% of the browser width. You can observe this by using the Chrome debugger and hovering over the element in the document tree.

Your image is not expanding with it because you are setting a fixed 100px width on the `.picture` container. If you took out that, the image would be as much as its actual width or the width of the browser viewport - whichever is lower. If you want the height of the list item to match the height of the image, you need to take out `position: absolute` and `left:0` on `.picture`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BAqir

```
.picture {
  min-height:100px;
  max-height:auto;
}
```

TIP: Make sure to properly nest your li and div. You don't really need the div in there and could apply the class directly on the li.